# Jquery change SVG class and fragment identifier depending on their it's parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, addclass, removeclass

I'm working on a progress bar with steps, they're two SVG icons, a check-mark, and a down arrow being loaded via a SVG sprite.

The down-arrow is the indicator of what step you're currently on in the progress bar.

This is the bar with a check mark.

```
  <li class="progress-done">
    <center>
      <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg class="icon-check-mark">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-check-mark"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <span class="progress-text">Assistance</span>
    </center>
  </li>
```

For the current step, there's an additional class added to the li element called "progress-current".

```
  <li class="progress-done progress-current">
    <center>
      <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg class="icon-check-mark">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-check-mark"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <span class="progress-text">Assistance</span>
    </center>
  </li>
```

Here's the full Codepen for the progress bar.

http://codepen.io/covanant/pen/YXRMrY

What I'm trying to accomplish is whenever the "progress-current" class is present, jQuery will change the SVG class and fragment identifier from "icon-check-mark" to "icon-down-arrow".

Note: The SVG class and fragment identifier always have the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put both `<use>` elements in your SVG?

```
  <li class="progress-done">
    <center>
      <div class="icon-wrap">
        <svg class="icon-check-mark">
          <use xlink:href="#icon-check-mark" class="check-ref"></use>
          <use xlink:href="#icon-down-arrow" class="down-ref"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <span class="progress-text">Assistance</span>
    </center>
  </li>
```

Then define `down-ref` to be hidden by default.

```
.down-ref {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then switch the visibility when `progress-current` is set.

```
.progress-current svg use.check-ref {
   visibility: hidden;
}

.progress-current svg use.down-ref {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

No JS needed.